# Spring security custom AuthenticationException message

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

Hi i needed to add a new exception in Spring security login form, everything work perfectly except that i want to have my own error message (until now it display the "wrong login/password" one).

I have override default attempt authentication method from Username password Authentication Filter :

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
{
if (!myTest()) {
throw new CustomAuthenticationException("custom message");
}
}
```

My exception :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationException extends AuthenticationException {

    public CustomAuthenticationException(final String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

    public CustomAuthenticationException(final String message, final Throwable cause)
    {
        super(message, cause);
    }

}
```

In my controller i see my exception under SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION but the error message is always the one from bad credentials, how could i change that ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to show the different message in the login page or in the log file? If it login page you need to configure it: `<form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1"/>`

Comment: In the login page, their is mapping somewhere for every AuthenticationException (BadCredentialsException, LockedException... see in org.springframework.security.authentication) from the exception to the custom message, i want to display my own error message.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should try **LOCALIZING SPRING SECURITY MESSAGES**.
Try adding these lines into your `ApplicationContext.xml` file. Where the rest of your spring security beans are.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="yourFolder/myMessages"/>
</bean>
```

You should find your spring default class which `<KEY, MESSAGE>` are stored. Have your `myMessage` file with the same `KEY`s and localized `MESSAGE`s.

---

Based on your comment, you have a `messages.properties` in your project. So all you need to do is to have a `MESSAGE` for each of these keys inside this property file, to have a fully localized messages:

```
AbstractAccessDecisionManager.accessDenied= your message in any language
AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticationNotFound=
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.credentialsExpired=
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.disabled=
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.expired=
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.locked=
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.onlySupports=
AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.credentialsExpired=
AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.disabled=
AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.expired=
AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.locked=
AclEntryAfterInvocationProvider.noPermission=
AnonymousAuthenticationProvider.incorrectKey=
BindAuthenticator.badCredentials=
BindAuthenticator.emptyPassword=
CasAuthenticationProvider.incorrectKey=
CasAuthenticationProvider.noServiceTicket=
ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.exceededAllowed=
DigestAuthenticationFilter.incorrectRealm=
DigestAuthenticationFilter.incorrectResponse=
DigestAuthenticationFilter.missingAuth=
DigestAuthenticationFilter.missingMandatory=
DigestAuthenticationFilter.nonceCompromised=
DigestAuthenticationFilter.nonceEncoding=
DigestAuthenticationFilter.nonceExpired=
DigestAuthenticationFilter.nonceNotNumeric=
DigestAuthenticationFilter.nonceNotTwoTokens=
DigestAuthenticationFilter.usernameNotFound=
JdbcDaoImpl.noAuthority=
JdbcDaoImpl.notFound=
LdapAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=
LdapAuthenticationProvider.credentialsExpired=
LdapAuthenticationProvider.disabled=
LdapAuthenticationProvider.expired=
LdapAuthenticationProvider.locked=
LdapAuthenticationProvider.emptyUsername=
LdapAuthenticationProvider.onlySupports=
PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.badCredentials=
PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.cookieStolen=
ProviderManager.providerNotFound=
RememberMeAuthenticationProvider.incorrectKey=
RunAsImplAuthenticationProvider.incorrectKey=
SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor.noMatching=
SwitchUserFilter.noCurrentUser=
SwitchUserFilter.noOriginalAuthentication=
```

Comment: Yes i have a message resource already, but what is the key for my custom exception ?

Comment: Updated the answer for you. All you have to do is set a `MESSAGE` for each key.

Comment: Why don't you provide a feedback? You could accept this as an answer if that solved your problem or promote it if you've found it useful.

Comment: Hi Matin,
Please tell me about getting messages according to locale.I am having trouble in getting chinese messages in chinese locale.

Comment: Dear @MatinKh, could you answer to my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63339729/how-to-customize-spring-security-messages-in-spring-boot-2-3-1

Comment: @RasoolGhafari it has been a very long time that I've not been around Spring. So, probably I'm not the best person to answer this question. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

In your messages.properties (or whatever you named it), add a line like:

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=The credentials you supplied are invalid.
```

You don't need a CustomAuthenticationException.

Comment: Worked for me on Spring boot

Answer (score 1):

Create a property file in class path like loginMessage.properties

In that property file, specify

AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Username/Password entered is incorrect.

Add the following bean in your applicationContext.xml,

```
<bean id="messageSource"   
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">  
    <property name="basenames">  
        <list>
            <value>loginMessage</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

After that, u'll get message like Username/Password entered is incorrect. instead of Bad Credentials

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is defining your custom message in exception handler (@ControllerAdvice), as following:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(value = AuthenticationException.class)
public ResponseModal handleAuthenticationExceptions(AuthenticationException ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
    LOGGER.info("Authentication Exception: {}", ex.getMessage());
    response.addCookie(new Cookie(JWTConfigurer.JWT_TOKEN_COOKIE, null));
    return new ResponseModal(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "whatever you want");
}
```