# Spring Security - Authentication Failure - Blank Message

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a spring-mvc web application.

On my login page if user enters bad credentials I want to display an error message.

So I tried to use spring security for showing error message, but I am get unable to display any message.

**login.jsp**

for login form I have done binding as :

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" id="loginForm">
.... login ui
</form>
```

for displaying the error:

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
    <div>
        <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

**security-context.xml**

```
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home" always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
```

after enabling all this options still unable to display error message on bad credentials provided.

Do let me know if you want any other info.

PS: On a quick note, rest entire config and application is working fine. Users are able to login. I have extended the UserDetailsContextMapper, and in that for anonymous users I am throwing an exception **UsernameNotFoundException**

Comment: Have you tried to change the test to `<c:if test="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION}">`

Comment: @jny: I tried.. that's empty :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the issue. This messages are stored in session and on my page I kept:

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
```

I changed it to:

```
<%@ page session="true"%>
```

and it started working. Another good info I got is, after all this if you want show your custom error messages, it is very simple to override those messages. For detailed info refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759264/spring-security-custom-authenticationexception-message) link.