# Spring Security - authentication failure message without redirects

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

How to show authentication failure message without any redirects in Spring Security?

I can find similar questions, like [How to display error message in my JSP page using spring security 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843913/how-to-display-error-message-in-my-jsp-page-using-spring-security-2-0) and [Spring Security - Authentication Failure - Blank Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989288/spring-security-authentication-failure-blank-message) where described bad way of doing it.

I don't like usage of **authentication-failure-url** attribute. All what I need is to show error message after HTTP POST request on login page **without any redirects** and **without using session**. Just put error variable into login model.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is in your login page do a AJAX call to `/j_spring_security_check` with `j_username` and `j_password`.

And you have to write a Custom [AuthenticationFailureHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html) and Plug it to [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java).setAuthenticationFailureHandler method. And a Custom [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.java) and [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java).setAuthenticationSuccessHandler method.

Your custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler should return true. Your custom AuthenticationFailureHandler should return false and your Login Page AJAX callback should check these values and take appropriate login action.

Comment: I agree, that AJAX is one of possible solutions here. But still it's not fully what I want. Just post data and get same login page with error message. This is so primitive but looks like extremely hard with Spring Security. One of way to do it, I think, is to write AuthenticationFailureHandler, that will put login page with error message to **response** in **onAuthenticationFailure** method. But this looks a little bit ugly.

Comment: Another option would be write a controller to handle login post method in which you set SecurityContextHolder object if authentication is successful. That way you can implement whatever the behaviour you want without relying on SpringSecurity's default authentication handling process flow.