# Spring Authentication, how to customize responeText for bad credential

Tags: java, spring, authentication

Mu authentication service is

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException, ResourceNotFoundException {

        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByUsername(s);

        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {

            User user = optionalUser.get();
            if (!user.isActive()) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User is not active.");
            }

            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

            if (user.isKeyUser()) grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_KEYUSER"));
            if (user.isAdmin()) grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));

            UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
            return userDetails;
        }
        else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }

    }
}
```

But when i try to make a login with wrong credential or user not active, I receive this generic error (I'm using React + Axios):

```
data: {error: "invalid_grant", error_description: "Bad credentials"}
```

Instead I would like to have the specific error: "***User is not active.***" or "***User not found***"

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Just an opinion: You should return "Bad credentials" or better "Bad combination of user and password". Don't expose an information, that the user is not found or active. You might use it for the logging, however the final user should be not aware whether he tries a combination for an existing user...

Answer (score 1):

As seen in this blog post you have to configure a MessageSource Bean. This bean you can configure to provide Messages as you like. The common approach would be to have a property files containing the messages.

```
 @Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.addBasenames("classpath:org/springframework/security/messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Please follow the Blog post [Configure Error Message](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/08/localization-spring-security-error-messages-spring-boot/) to have a deeper look into the topic

Answer (score 0):

You can **override message property of spring-security-core.jar.** For that,
create message property file add key and value pair of this,

**AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Invalid username or password**

and
then

just add following code to your xml configuation

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
        <value>mymessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

By this, You can override multiple default properties of spring-framework

You can refer following site for details,

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/display-custom-error-message-in-spring-security/

or

[Spring security custom AuthenticationException message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759264/spring-security-custom-authenticationexception-message)