# How to customize spring security messages in spring boot 2.3.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, internationalization

I've defined this below bean as message source:

```
@Bean("messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("i18n/messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

and this is content of `messages.properties` file under `src/main/resources/i18n/` folder:

```
ExceptionTranslationFilter.insufficientAuthentication=A Custom message
AbstractAccessDecisionManager.accessDenied=A Custom message
```

Now, i expected to see **A Custom message** when an unauthorized user calls the rest, but get **Full authentication is required to access this resource** that is spring default exception message.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @joachim I checked the several ways, but didn't result. please share or answer here it if you find a solution.